# Clarification on Sitecore link database sycronization in muliti-server environments

Tags: sitecore

The Sitecore Guide states this:

> To ensure that Sitecore automatically updates the link database in the
>   CD environment:
>
> *The CD and CM instances must use the same name to refer to the publishing target database across the environments (typically Web).
>
> One of the following conditions should be met:
>
> **The Core database should be shared or replicated between the CM and CD instances.
>
> ** The Link database data should be configured to be stored in a database which is shared between CM and CD publishing target database
>   (typically Web).

Two things aren't clear to me:

1. The line with the first *, I assume this means that if I have two web DBs, one being "web" and the other being "web2", then this means that the CM needs to use those names and CD1 needs to use "web" and CD2 needs to use "web2", yes"?
2. The last line with **: by "shared" does this mean that CD1 and CD2 would need to use the same web database, or does it just mean that as long as CM, CD1 and CD2 are set to use their respective web DBs to store the Link DB, the Link DB will be updated on publish? What database should the CM be configured to store it's like DB? It has two webs (web1, web2).

Here are details of our environment for context:
Our CM environment is 1 web server and 1 DB server. Our CD environment is two load balanced web servers, each with their own DB. So, two publishing targets for the CM to point to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. Typically you may have multiple web DBs for things such as pre production preview, e.g. "webpreview" as opposed to a public "web" DB. If you have two separate web DBs, "web1" and "web2" and two separate CDs use them respectively, then it seems you must have two separate publishing targets, web1 and web2. In the typical case (where "typical" maybe just means simple), there's a single web DB shared by 1-n CDs. So in your case CD1 and CD2 would both read from the same single web DB. Based on this context:

1. It means whatever connection string 'name' token you use on the CM for the "web" DB, you need to use the same token on CD1 and CD2. So it could be "web" or "webpublic" or similar. But must be consistent across all 3 instances (CM, CD1, CD2)
2. Yes, CD1 and CD2 would share the same exact web DB as I indicated above. And thus you would set the link database to use that shared "web" (or "webpublic"...) DB.

Comment: To clarify, when I say that we have two CDs, I mean they're both public servers (load balanced) and our CM publishes directly to them. You're answers make sense, but ultimately I'm looking for an answer to if what you outlined above is sufficient to keep the Link DBs in sync across CM, and both CD DBs. If the answer is yes, then I assume that the link DB data is synced during publish?

Comment: Ok. So since you have two publishin targets and thus need to publish to two separate web DBs, you need another DB to hold the Links. In this case, I recommend you configure Links to use the Core DB. That assumes CM, CD1, and CD2 all share the same Core DB.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what are the implications are of not having them synced in our set up?

Comment: If you don't use the Links database in code then there are no implications on a CD instance =)